# Queue throwing out of memory exception in flood fill

Tags: c#, queue, out-of-memory

I'm doing a flood fill on a 2000 x 2000 x 256 bitmap (in memory) using the code from here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Flood_fill#C.23

The Queue is throwing an out of memory error when q Count = 33554432 (~33MB). Obviously, I've got plenty more memory than that. I've also created a struct of IntPoint so each point is 2 ints instead of 2 doubles.

1. Is there a way to manually allocate more memory for the Queue?
2. If that isn't possible, does anybody have any other suggestions?

FYI: I doubt if this is important, but I'm actually doing the flood fill on a 2000 x 2000 array of bytes in memory as opposed to actually loading a bitmap, checking colors and replacing.

Below is my implementation of the flood fill from the above referenced link (maybe a glaring error will jump out):

```
public struct IntPoint
    {
        public int X, Y;

        public IntPoint(int p1, int p2)
        {
            X = p1;
            Y = p2;
        }
    }


    public void TerrainFloodFill(Point Tpt, byte targetElevation, byte replacementTerrain)
    {
        IntPoint pt = new IntPoint((int)Tpt.X, (int)Tpt.Y);

        Queue<IntPoint> q = new Queue<IntPoint>();
        q.Enqueue(pt);
        while (q.Count > 0)
        {
            IntPoint n = q.Dequeue();
            if (HeightMap[(int)n.X, (int)n.Y] != targetElevation)
                continue;
            IntPoint w = n, e = new IntPoint(n.X + 1, n.Y);
            while ((w.X > 0) && HeightMap[(int)w.X, (int)w.Y] == targetElevation)
            {
                TerrainMap[(int)w.X, (int)w.Y] = replacementTerrain;
                if ((w.Y > 0) && HeightMap[(int)w.X, (int)w.Y - 1] == targetElevation)
                    q.Enqueue(new IntPoint(w.X, w.Y - 1));
                if ((w.Y < MapHeight - 1) && HeightMap[(int)w.X, (int)w.Y + 1] == targetElevation)
                    q.Enqueue(new IntPoint(w.X, w.Y + 1));
                w.X--;
            }
            while ((e.X < MapWidth - 1) && HeightMap[(int)e.X, (int)e.Y] == targetElevation)
            {
                TerrainMap[(int)e.X, (int)e.Y] = replacementTerrain;
                if ((e.Y > 0) && HeightMap[(int)e.X, (int)e.Y - 1] == targetElevation)
                    q.Enqueue(new IntPoint(e.X, e.Y - 1));
                if ((e.Y < MapHeight - 1) && HeightMap[(int)e.X, (int)e.Y + 1] == targetElevation)
                    q.Enqueue(new IntPoint(e.X, e.Y + 1));
                e.X++;
            }
        }

    }
```

As always, thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a fragmentation problem, you should really use a memory profiler to find out what happens.

As a first stab,

```
  int estimatedSize = ...;
  Queue<IntPoint> q = new Queue<IntPoint>(estimatedSize);
```

I think something like `int estimatedSize = MapWidth;` would be a good start.

---

But your queue is still getting too big.  The original algorithm can fail when `targetColor == replacementColor`, in your case it is because `HeightMap != TerrainMap`. You need to operate on the *same* map so that setting a 'pixel' will make sure it isn't re-queued when its neighbors are examined.

So start by copying the entire HeightMap to the TerrainMap first.

Comment: First, thanks for the suggestion. It's running OOM around 60 MB regardless of how high I set the estimated size  int estimatedSize = MapHeight * MapWidth * sizeof(int) * 2;

Comment: Where (when) does it run oom? And you should go back to `struct`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm back to a struct now.

Comment: Sizes are in elements, your initial error was at 33M * 4B = 132 MB. You won't need `sizeof(int)` very often in C#.

Comment: Try it with `estimatedSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;` although I think your algo shouldn't need so much. It might be looping 'forever' somewhere, look over all the boundary conditions again.

Comment: Bombed immediately on   int estimatedSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024; It couldn't allocate that much memory (would be my guess).

Comment: FYI: it OOM when Count = 32000000 and on this line:      q.Enqueue(new IntPoint(e.X, e.Y + 1)); I wonder if it is an infinite loop...

Comment: @Henk... wow... hadn't thought of that. Obviously, I've got two different 2000 x 2000 x 256 matrices. One is a matrix of elevation, the other is a matrix of 'terrain types'. I thought I would just use a flood fill algorithm (I want to paint all adjoining elevation in the same 'terrain type' such as 'fresh water' for a lake). I think you've hit upon the problem... now what is the solution? Maybe create a THIRD 2000 x 2000 x 256 matrix, copy the HeightMap to it, perform the algorithm, then copy only the new values to the TerrainMap and then delete the third matrix?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30635/discussion-between-zetar-and-henk-holterman)

Comment: No, i don't use chat. Hard to combine with other stuff.

Comment: Oh, well, I was just thanking you (more profusely) and telling you that this is the project that I'm working on: http://dinosaur-island.com. This bit is part of the 'landscaping' the island routines. Again, many thanks!

Comment: OK, good luck with it. You can indeed use a third matrix, or destroy the HeightMap in the process. As long as you can tell that you have already visited a point.

Comment: And BTW, the estimatedSize trick still stands for large collections. prevents a 4,8,16,32 grow curve.

Comment: It actually does the 'color' replacement very fast. It takes < 1 second to 'color' all the terrain around the island as 'Salt Water' as a flood fill.

Answer (score 0):

structs are immutable, and each modification of them creates a new object, just like primitive types. I see some X++; and X--; modifications to the struct. Try making IntPoint a class instead so that the reference doesn't keep getting new'd up and see if that improves things.

Comment: Structs _should be_ immutable, this one isn't.

Comment: Right. I guess what I meant is he's creating a lot of copies of the structure by modifying it.

Comment: Changed it to a class and it got further. Out of memory at: count = 59517893 (~ 59 MB). I don't know why it the Queue would get this big, either.

Comment: Those copies only end up in the heap with `EnQueue()` and that's when they have to. All other copies are on the stack and do not matter.

Comment: @zetar - simply changing it to a class will make that `w = n` now means something completely different. Your algorithm is likely to fail now.

Comment: Okay, so I'm back to a struct... and running OOM at 64 MB. I really wouldn't have guessed that the Queue would get THAT big.